# Select object from array of objects in Postgres

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a table `questions` where `options` is `jsonb` which is an array of objects.

```
"questions": [
        {
            "id": 76,
            "text": "What is the capital of Telangana ?",
            "options": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "text": "Hyderabad",
                    "correct": true
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "text": "Bangalore",
                    "correct": false
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "text": "Amaravathi",
                    "correct": false
                },
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "text": "Chennai",
                    "correct": false
                }
            ],
            "position": 1
        }
```

Can someone help how can I select an `option` object from `options` by a given `id` using **PostgreSql**?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can select it. [unnest](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) and filter, eg:

```
t=# with c(j) as (values('{"options": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "text": "Hyderabad",
                    "correct": true
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "text": "Bangalore",
                    "correct": false
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "text": "Amaravathi",
                    "correct": false
                },
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "text": "Chennai",
                    "correct": false
                }
            ]}'::jsonb))
, m as (select jsonb_array_elements(j->'options') a from c) select a from m where a->>'id' = '3';
                         a
---------------------------------------------------
 {"id": 3, "text": "Amaravathi", "correct": false}
(1 row)
```